# Tutorial for ServiceMix 4.2

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I try to figure out a start with Apache ServiceMix 4.2

**Sadly the tutorials on the homesite seem pretty much outdated** ... with 4.2 the services seem to be started out of the box and be configured with karaf, while the tutorials talk about copying files into a "hotdeploy" folder that doesn't exist anymore in 4.2 ...

Can someone point me to a tutorial thats valid for ServiceMix 4.2? I'm trying to test the communication of two simple HelloWorld webservices or see how to configure a BC to wire in a webservice or something like this, just to get started. Would appreciate any help or pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [FUSE ESB](http://fusesource.com/products/enterprise-servicemix/) which is based on servicemix and free. It has some good documentation which you maybe also can use to understand servicemix itself.

Comment: Thanks! Found this while googleing before, but thought the FUSE stuff was something commercial on top of ServiceMix ... looking at the examples, it seems they just labeled it FUSE to sell their ServiceMix erperience ... Thanks anyways!

Comment: The FUSE team announced the next major version release (FUSE ESB 4.3.0-fuse-00-00) for tomorrow (http://fusesource.com/wiki/display/FUSEESB/Home). Maybe it is worth waiting - although I do not know how quick documentation updates will be available.

Answer (score 4):

here are a couple quick guides for setting up your dev box and getting a basic bundle created and deployed...

http://benoday.blogspot.com/2010/08/servicemix-developer-machine-setup.html

http://benoday.blogspot.com/2010/08/fuse-esb-42-and-osgi-quick-start-guide.html

Answer (score 2):

Wrote a small getting started guide that helps you beginning with Service Mix 4.2:

http://www.ithoughts.de/getting-started-with-servicemix-4-2-and-webservices-with-maven-and-eclipse-on-windows

Comment: Just a remark: this will be pretty much outdated now. Just browsed through meta.stackoverflow to see if it should be deleted, but I will leave it here as it might be a starting point for desperate service mixers. I still hope that someone might edit or comment better tutorials here.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a few tutorials on ServiceMix using JBI ([Part 1](http://www.softwarepassion.com/servicemix-fuse-esb-file-su-jms-su-example-part-1/), [Part 2](http://www.softwarepassion.com/servicemix-fuse-esb-%E2%80%93-file-su-jms-su-example-%E2%80%93-part-2/), [Part 3](http://www.softwarepassion.com/servicemix-fuse-esb-%E2%80%93-bean-service-unit-%E2%80%93-part-3/)) and Camel OSGI bundle ([Part 4](http://www.softwarepassion.com/servicemix-fuseesb-camel-osgi-example-part-4/)) on the softwarepassion.com website